# How to edit a table field value in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In PHPMyAdmin, I am looking at a table, but I see no way to edit a table entry (not sure of the correct terminology sorry).

[image]

The value I want to edit is `DisableAdminPWReset` (to 0).

How do I do this? There are no methods of editing this value that I can see. I am a SQL newb too.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` statment: `UPDATE tblconfiguration SET value='0' WHERE setting='DisableAdminPWReset'`

Comment: And the reason you can't edit it directly in phpMyAdmin is probably because the table does not have an index. When a table has an index phpMyAdmin will let you double click on the column value you want to change and edit it.

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin do you have? There was a recent feature addition that should have helped with this, which was part of the 4.5.0 release.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch. Using 4.0.10.7, bundled with my host's cpanel. It says: `A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.6.0`. I will see what my host says about this.

Comment: Web host says I can install `4.6.0` if I wish, but cpanel is responsible for updating `phpMyAdmin` to `4.6.0` for the standard install of `phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problem now. Following Dave's instructions on an answer above I was going to try to put an index on the table, but I've realized that normalized tables usually have a primary key configured. It was enough to enable editing table lines. I've just entered the table structure tab and clicked at my table primary key "primary" button/link to turn it formally into the primary key and the "problem" was solved.